# Finding optimal x given symmetric matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, symmetric-matrices

Trying to find $$\text{min} \{x | xI-A\succeq 0\}$$ where a $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

This seems pretty simple but I'm not quite sure where to start. I was taking the derivative of $xI-A$ but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: you can also find the answer by relating the eigenvalues of $A$ to the eigenvalues of $xI - A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = U \Lambda U^{\mathsf{T}}$ be the spectral decomposition of $A$. Then we can rewrite:
$$
x I - A = x UU^{\mathsf{T}} - UDU^{\mathsf{T}} = U \left(x I - D \right) U^{\mathsf{T}}
$$

Because $U \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$ is an orthogonal matrix, requiring $U(xI - D) U^{\mathsf{T}} \succeq 0$ is equivalent to requiring $xI - D \succeq 0$. The smallest $x$ that satisfies this is equal to $\max_{i} D_{ii} = \lambda_{\max}(A)$.